# Quill Editor does not support Tamil font. How to fix the problem?

Tags: android, admin, quill

Quill Editor does not support Tamil font. How to fix the problem?

Posted the first time this was shown correctly once the post was edited blog was wrong in the editor.

I changed many Tamil fonts but does not support them. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Bro provide more details about the issue, Say detail about what you tried and what error you have got, you can follow this reference on [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) So we can further help you, Please provide your [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code, so we can further help you.

Comment: bro code ithutha provide pannuga, so apo thaan ongaluku help panna mudiyum